# AngularJs ng-repeat custom structure

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a dataset like this

```
$scope.dataset= [ 
    {"Name":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","Country":"Germany"}, 
    {"Name":"Ana Trujillo","City":"México D.F.","Country":"Mexico"}, 
    {"Name":"Antonio Moreno Taquería","City":"México D.F.","Country":"Mexico"}, 
    {"Name":"Around the Horn","City":"London","Country":"UK"} 
];
```

I want to print this in this manner link this

```html
<div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
      .......
      .......
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
      .......
      .......
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
      .......
      .......
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
      .......
      .......
      </div>
   </div>

    ......
    ......
</div>
```

I can achieve this by slice the dataset by two pieces of packets. But my problem is i have some operations like sort, filter over the dataset.

So please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: What result at the end, what you want to be printed

Comment: I want to print name, city and country like the html structure. I tried ng-repeat on the "class=row" div. But it does not full fill my requirement. I want to print two dataset in one row.I want use only one ng-repeat.

Comment: Where is your other dataset and can you show your output in plain html so that we can help you

Comment: @SaikatGuin If you have 2 datasets, please provide the two so we can help you, and also provide an example of the output you are expecting, because currently I can not see a problem with a single `ngRepeat` as to the example you provided.

Comment: @SaikatGuin I guess by two datasets you mean two objects of the dataset array which you want to display in one row. Isn't so?

Comment: Here is the demo jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/hh5bthu9/     I want two col-md-6 data in a class row.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understand this is what you are trying to achieve.See result in full page. If you have more than one dataset like $scope.dataset1, $scope.dataset2 then you can merge using $.merge(dataset1, dataset2) or angular.merge({}, dataset1, dataset2) function then apply filters on it.
**Edit:**
    I modified the code as per the jsfiddle. See the result in full page

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("MainCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.dataset= [ 
    {"Name":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","Country":"Germany"}, 
    {"Name":"Ana Trujillo","City":"México D.F.","Country":"Mexico"}, 
    {"Name":"Antonio Moreno Taquería","City":"México D.F.","Country":"Mexico"}, 
    {"Name":"Around the Horn","City":"London","Country":"UK"} 
];
  $scope.dataset2= [ 
    {"Name":"Alfreds Futterkiste1","City":"Berlin","Country":"Germany"}, 
    {"Name":"Ana Trujillo1","City":"México D.F.","Country":"Mexico"}, 
    {"Name":"Antonio Moreno Taquería1","City":"México D.F.","Country":"Mexico"}, 
    {"Name":"Around the Horn1","City":"London","Country":"UK"} 
];  
});
```

```css
.color{
      background-color: beige;
          margin-bottom: 13px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row color">
        <div ng-repeat="c in dataset">
          <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="row">{{c.Name}}</div>
            <div class="row">{{c.City}}</div>
            <div class="row">{{c.Country}}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="row color">
        <div ng-repeat="c in dataset2">
          <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="row">{{c.Name}}</div>
            <div class="row">{{c.City}}</div>
            <div class="row">{{c.Country}}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: here is the html structure i want to print like this https://jsfiddle.net/nw9bqeho/

Answer (score 1):

@nivas I want the data like this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="container">
      <div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">Alfreds</div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">Berlin</div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">Germany</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">Ana Trujillo</div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">Berlin</div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">Germany</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">Alfreds1</div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">Berlin</div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">Germany</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">Ana Trujillo1</div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">Berlin</div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">Germany</div>
        </div>
      </div>
        
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">Alfreds2</div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">Berlin</div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">Germany</div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @nivas i have only one dataset. With one dataset i have to run ng-repeat in a way that will print the output like https://jsfiddle.net/nw9bqeho/

Comment: I have quick question how many rows you want to print like that and what is the difference between them

Answer (score 0):

```
try this:


    <head>
        <script src =   "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">  </script>
 <style>
        th , td {
            display: block;
        }
        tr { display: block; float: left; }
        .color {
            background-color: beige;
            margin-bottom: 13px;
        }

        .one-row {
            display: inline-block;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="yourApp">
        <div ng-controller="yourControllerName">
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>Country</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="data in yourDatasetName" class="color">
                    <td>{{data.Name}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.City}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.Country}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <script>
            var mainApp = angular.module("yourApp",[]);
            mainApp.controller("yourControllerName", function ($scope) {
            $scope.yourDatasetName= [
                {"Name":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","Country":"Germany"},
                {"Name":"Ana Trujillo","City":"México D.F.","Country":"Mexico"},
                {"Name":"Antonio Moreno Taquería","City":"México        D.F.","Country":"Mexico"},
                {"Name":"Around the Horn","City":"London","Country":"UK"}
            ];
            });
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: I want to print the data like this https://jsfiddle.net/nw9bqeho/     .

Comment: add this code :
 <style>
        th , td {
            display: block;
        }
        tr { display: block; float: left; }
        .color {
            background-color: beige;
            margin-bottom: 13px;
        }

        .one-row {
            display: inline-block;
        }
    </style>

Comment: I,ve modified my answer,did you try that?@SaikatGuin